# iPhone dynamic addition of UILabel overlap

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am parsing the XML file through URL and displaying the values as label dynamically.

If values are changed in xml file, the new values of labels are overlapped on old values

How should i fix it

```
In viewDidLoad

for(int i=0;i<[appDelegate.books count]; i++){
[self createLabel:labelname labelFrame:CGRectMake(LXCOOR, LYCOOR,LWIDTH,LHEIGHT)];
}

-(void) createLabel :(NSString * ) aTitle labelFrame:(CGRect) aFrame{



    label1 =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame];
    //label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:TEXTSIZE];
    label1.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 10];
    label1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    label1.text=[NSString stringWithString:aTitle];

    label1.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [sv addSubview:label1];

    [self.view addSubview:sv];


}
```

Comment: This is a wrong way of doing your work. You should not keep adding labels instead you should just keep changing the text of a single label you added.

Comment: could you please post the code

Answer (score 0):

remove the sv before adding it to the view...

```
-(void) createLabel :(NSString * ) aTitle labelFrame:(CGRect) aFrame{


    if ([[sv subviews] count] > 0)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i< [[sv subviews] count] ; i++)
    {
        UIView *subView = [[sv subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
        [subView removeFromSuperview];
        i++;
    }
}
    [sv removeFromSuperView];
    label1 =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame];
    //label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:TEXTSIZE];
    label1.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 10];
    label1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    label1.text=[NSString stringWithString:aTitle];

    label1.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [sv addSubview:label1];

    [self.view addSubview:sv];


}
```

Comment: only last two labels are displayed

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad add,

```
[self.view addSubview:sv];
```

Then modify the "createLabel" function to

```
-(void) createLabel :(NSString * ) aTitle labelFrame:(CGRect) aFrame{

for(UIView *tempView in [sv subviews]) {
   [subView removeFromSuperview];
}

    label1 =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame];
    //label.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:TEXTSIZE];
    label1.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 10];
    label1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    label1.text=[NSString stringWithString:aTitle];

    label1.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    [sv addSubview:label1];




}
```

Comment: Same issue persists, sv is scrollview

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned above, you shouldn't recreate the label over and over. Instead you should create one instance of it in viewDidLoad (or something that loads once)

```
-(void)viewDidLoad { ...
    //code
    CGRect aFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
    label1 =[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame];
    [sv addSubview:label1];
    [self.view addSubview:sv];
}
```

next you should call createLabel where you want to, for instance a button click or a scroll gesture. This should be your new createLabel without adding a subview

```
-(void) createLabel :(NSString * ) aTitle labelFrame:(CGRect) aFrame{

    label1.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 10];
    label1.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    label1.text=[NSString stringWithString:aTitle];

    label1.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

}